# Exclude the last character of a regex match

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
%(?:\\.|[^%\\ ])*%([,;\\\s])
```

That works great but obviously it also highlights the next character to the last `%`.

I was wondering how could I exclude it from the regex?

For instance, if I have:

```
The files under users\%username%\desktop\ are:
```

It will highlight `%username%\` but I just want `%username%`. On the other hand, if I leave the regex like this:

```
%(?:\\.|[^%\\ ])*%
```

...then it will match this pattern that I don't want to:

```
%example1%example2%example3
```

Any idea how to exclude the last character in the match through a regex?

Comment: I think I found a solution with a brand new RegEx... sorry for posting this too early! This does what I need... 

`%(?:\\.|[^" %\d\\])*%`

Comment: This regex is not effecient, as you have an alternation group with a quantifier applied. If it is not an issue (the strings you have a short) it is OK. If they can be a bit longer, you need to unroll it. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM2cY3/1) - 6 steps vs. 30.

Comment: Did any of the answers help? Please consider accepting the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a more effecient regex than you are currently using. When alternation is used together with a quantifier, there is unnecessary backtracking involved.

If the strings you have are short, it is OK to use. However, if they can be a bit longer, you may need to "unroll" the expression.

Here is how it is done:

```
%[^"\\%]*(?:\\.[^"\\%]*)*%
```

Regex breakdown:

- `%` - initial percentage sign
- `[^"\\%]*` - start of the unrolled pattern: 0 or more characters other than a double quote, backslash and percentage sign
- `(?:\\.[^"\\%]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of...

  - `\\.` - a literal backslash followed by any character other than a newline
  - `[^"\\%]*` - 0 or more characters other than a double quote, backslash and percentage sign
- `%` - trailing percentage sign

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM2cY3/1) - 6 steps vs. 30 steps with your [`%(?:\\.|[^" %\d\\])*%`](https://regex101.com/r/dS2kH0/1).

Answer (score 5):

```
%(?:\\.|[^%\\ ])*%(?=[,;\\\s])

                   ^^
```

Use a `lookahead`.What you need here is `0 width assertion` which does not capture anything.